# I want to transfer a variable to an extended class without changing its value to null

Tags: java

This is what I've created till now and I want to transfer the value of q defined in  class `Subway` to extended class `Billing`

**Subway:**

```
// This is the main part of the program from where everything will start

import java.util.*;

public class Subway extends Billing {

    public static void menu() {

        Scanner obj1 = new Scanner(System.in);

        Subway obj2 = new Subway();

        int a = 1;
        int b = 1;
        int c = 1;

        System.out.println("Loading...");

        for (a = 1; a <= 999999999; a++) {

        }

        for (b = 1; b <= 999999999; b++) {

        }

        for (c = 1; c <= 999999999; c++) {

        }

        System.out.println("Program has been Loaded Successfully");

        System.out.println("Welcome to Subway....");

        System.out.println(
                "==============================================================================================================================================");

        System.out.println("Sandwiches\t\t\t\tMRP(₹)\tSnacks\t\t\t\t\tMRP(₹)\tBreakfast\t\t\t\tMRP(₹)");

        System.out.println(
                "Aloo Patty(AP)\t\t\t\t₹ \tChatpata Chana SubWrap(CCSW)\t\t₹\tChicken Slice,Eggs and Cheese(CSEC)\t₹");

        System.out.println("Chicken Kofta(CK)\t\t\t₹ \tChicken Kofta SubWrap(CKSW)\t\t₹\tCheese and Egg(CE)\t\t\t₹");

        System.out.println(
                "Chatpata Chana Patty(CCP)\t\t₹ \tChicken Strips SubWrap(CSSW)\t\t₹\tWestern Cheese and Egg(WCE)\t\t₹");

        System.out.println(
                "Chicken Slices(CS)\t\t\t₹ \tVeg Shammi SubWrap(VSSW)\t\t₹\t==============================================");

        System.out.println(
                "Chicken Tandoori(CTA)\t\t\t₹ \t==============================================================================================");

        System.out.println("Chicken Tikka(CTI)\t\t\t₹ \tSides\t\t\t\t\tMRP(₹)\tDrinks\t\t\t\t\tMRP(₹)");

        System.out.println("Corn and Peas(CP)\t\t\t₹ \tChips(Small)\t\t\t\t₹ \tMirinda(300ml)\t\t\t\t₹ ");

        System.out.println("Hara Bhara Kebab(HBK)\t\t\t₹ \tChips(Big)\t\t\t\t₹ \tMirinda(500ml)\t\t\t\t₹ ");

        // The menu is incompelete
        System.out.println("Enter the Code in the brackets to order your item:");
        String i = obj1.nextLine();
        String iU = i.toUpperCase();// to convert code to upper case
        System.out.println("Quantity: ");
        int q = obj1.nextInt();
        switch (iU) {
        case "AP":
            obj2.AP();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Billing:**

```
import java.util.*;

public class Billing {
    int pr = 0, amt = 0;// global variables for price and amount
    boolean flag = false;// for if else

    public void main() {
        System.out.println("Option not found in the menu");
    }

    public static void AP(int q) {
        int pr = 125, amt = 0;
        boolean flag = false;
        amt = pr * q;

    }
}
```

Please get me to the answer .
The problem will not be resolved by creating an object as that is refreshing the value to null. so please keep this in mind before you answer this question

Comment: Aside from a recommendation to not use variable names like abc, pr, or obj1: Why does `obj2.AP(q);` not work?

Comment: OK! I found the mistake. My argument parameter for `Billing` was empty before. I tried changing it and it works perfectly fine now. Thank you and also  can recommend me what variables should I use?

Comment: Like @MalteHartwig said, do not use abbreviations for variable names. Always write the full name. obj2 should be called subway. amt should be amount. q should be quantity maybe? Also notice that the methods you defined static should actually not be static. Because you are not calling them in a static way. And lastly the for loops you use to "fake" to loading could be replaced by a Thread.sleep(2000).

Comment: Well, I do not really know what the variables are used for, what they mean (even you would have a hard time understanding this if you have to look at it again in a month). And that is exactly what the names should help with. `obj1` could be something like `userInput`, `q` is `quantity` (there is no reason to use abbriviations), `iU` is `selectedItem` for example. For more advice on code style you should ask a question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @DavidMaes The thing is that I do want to shorten the program by using some advanced commands but I can't do it because we are not allowed to use commands that have not been taught to us in my school :( .I really want to get into these advanced commands.

Answer (score 1):

Your method AP has arguement of type int, but you leave it empty. Second your AP method is static, it's better approach to call static method with their class name like

```
Billing.AP(q);
```

It is recommended to use variable and method with their proper names like 
`int amount; String country;` etc.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
obj2.AP(q);
```

make this change on your Billing Class. it  should work.